# wget doesn't want to accept GET argument

Tags: wget

I need some help with wget!

I want to download a file, which has parameter in GET string:

```
/get.php?file=hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip&key=43e7ce13e9818c0b4c5737b7d061005606dfad5e
```

If I try to download this file with this argument, wget says it doesn't know the key field.
Key will be generated for every PC downloading file and will also have to read again and again. As far as I have no problem, but how do I get this key?

Comment: Show us the exact line you are trying to run.

Comment: wget "http://bootmii.org/get.php?file=hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip&amp;key=43e7ce13e9818c0b4c5737b7d061005606dfad5e"

Answer (score 4):

If the web page isn't downloading, make sure you quote the URL, like so:

```
wget "http://www.example.com/doThis?key=val&other=otherval"
```

If this works, the problem is due to the ampersand - the shell interprets that as "execute this command in the background" Putting the url in quotes will fix this.

Comment: But if I do this, I get a file like this: get.php@file=hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip&key=43e7ce13e9818c0b4c5737b7d061005606dfad5e

Comment: Append `-O "hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip"` to the command line to force the contents to be downloaded to that filename.

Comment: so how have to look like the full command? I didn't get it yet, what you want to tell me

Comment: If i use this command wget -O "hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip" "http://bootmii.org/get.php?file=hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip&key=43e7ce13e9818c0b4c5737b7d061005606dfad5e", I get a file hackmii_installer_v1.0.zip, but it isn't the zip-file I want! If I triy to edit it with notepadd++ it shows me the connection-way